# FTS query similar to LIKE 'a%'?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

Is it possible to leverage SQLite FTS index capabilities to get result similar to LIKE 'a%' query? There is MATCH 'a*' but its not the same, for example:

```
'hello world'
'say hello'
```

`LIKE 'he%'` would return only first record (this is what I need)

`MATCH 'he*'` would return both records

Is it possible to tell MATCH somehow to compare only beginnings of attributes?

Comment: I dont think its possible since by nature full text search will look for the whole word. But may be some once can have better idea of doing the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compiled with the enhanced query syntax, SQLite can search for the beginning of the entire string with `^`, i.e., `MATCH '^he*'`.